# Verify/Check to see if a Configuration Profile has been installed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, installation, validation

Does anyone know if there's an API to check to see if a particular Configuration Profile has been installed on a iOS device?

Thanks, Cole

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What kind of information do you want to grab from the Configuration Profile?

Comment: i'm working on an enterprise app - and one of our BR's is to ensure that a configuration profile has been installed that has a nondefault passcode payload added to it. the business doesn't want the app to work at all if this said configuration profile isn't installed. So just a BOOL that would return whether it's installed or not would be great.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this issue?

Comment: I did not - not sure if 4.2 made this possible.  I'm guessing Apple is wanting the Enterprise to configure/enable Mobile Device Management and push configuration profiles onto users whether they like it or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no API for that, but there is a workaround based on certificate validation. You have to create a self-signed root certificate and include it into your configuration profile. Then you have to create another certificate signed by this root certificate and include it into your application. When you need to verify if a configuration profile is installed, you may verify if that certificate is trusted. See Apple developer forums for details - https://devforums.apple.com/message/11142#11142

Comment: Is this approach working ? as of iOS 7,8,9 and all.  In the attached thread itself gives an impression that this approach fails and not consistent ! Can you please throw some light on this ?

Comment: I wrote up a full explanation of all the details for how to do this here: https://andrewking.ca/2020/04/how-to-enable-custom-debugging-in-release-builds/