iOS Check if there is an MDM device profile installed
How to check if there is any MDM profile installed in the ios device programtically.
As far as I see there is no public api to access it, are there some other ways to just check if there is any MDM profile active in the device.
REF : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21844059/3104485

There is no API.  You need to check with the MDM service.
