# Check if a mobileconfig profile is installed on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Install mobileconfig file through
([Installing a configuration profile on iPhone - programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically)) on iPhone Desktop.

#### How to check whether this config file is installed?

In iPhone `Settings->General->provision file`,I can find the list.

Comment: You mean check programmatically?

Comment: YES,check by programmatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came across a the following approach to *identify* if the *mobile config* is installed or not,But I have not tested though so far.

> There is no direct API available to do this.But there is a workaround
>   to achieve this by the means of *certificate trust verification*.
>
> If we attach a self-signed trust ca with mobile config and install
>   it on the device we can check if the mobile config is installed by
>   checking the trust level of the leaf certificate that is signed by the
>   self-signed root ca.That is ,If leaf certificate's trust verification is failed in the app means the mobile config is not installed or else installed

**Steps:**

- Create a *Self Signed Root CA* you can do it either using *Certificate Assistant* or *openssl* in terminal.
- Create *another Certificate* and get it *Signed* using the *Self Signed Root CA*
- Attach the *Signed Certificate* that is created in previous step to the xcode
- Attach the *Self Signed Root CA* as a part of the *Mobile Config*

  - Open your mobile config in the IPCU
  - Scroll down to *Credentials*
  - Press *Configure* on the right side
  - Select the *Self Signed Root CA* (make sure its in .cer format)

    [image: iPCU]
  - Export the *Mobile Config* now and signing it using *Globally Trusted CA* like GoDaddy.This step is optional if its is done the device will show the mobile config as *verified* or else it will show as *unverified* while installing mobile config.

---

**Code Snippet:**

```
-(BOOL)IsMobileConfigInstalled {

NSString* certPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LeafCertificate" ofType:@"cer"];

NSData* certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:certPath];

SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) certData);

SecPolicyRef policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();

SecTrustRef trust;

OSStatus err = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((__bridge CFArrayRef) [NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)cert], policy, &trust);

SecTrustResultType trustResult = -1;

err = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);

CFRelease(trust);

CFRelease(policy);

CFRelease(cert);

if(trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified)
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
}
```

---

**References:**

Here is the [link](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/3336?start=0&tstart=0) to a technical discussion around the topic in apple developer forum

Here is the [link](http://blog.markhorgan.com/?p=701) to a blog post that takes you step by step.

Here are the links to stack overflow discussions about this topic [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28278991/730807), [Ref22](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2195673/730807)

Comment: Thank you for putting the steps here and not just linking. The site seems dead so this post is very helpful.

Comment: The Apple Dev forums link is no longer valid, check this one instead: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/121584#121584

Comment: I wrote up a full detailed blog post about how to do this here: https://andrewking.ca/2020/04/how-to-enable-custom-debugging-in-release-builds/