# Check if a configuration profile is installed on iOS

Tags: ios, certificate, configuration-files

I'm trying to check if .mobileconfig file installed on the iOS device. I've tried an approach which described by this link http://blog.markhorgan.com/?p=701, but I'm fail with it. Maybe someone have other ideas or whatever ... ? Thank in advance.